# Accessing a generic object from within the API endpoint

Tags: c#, api, async-await

Normally I'd create a generic entity in my baseController and then import it to a service like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            entity = await _service.CreateAsync(entity);
            return Ok(entity);
        }
```

What I WANT to do is to import a csv file, access the generic object from within the HttpPost statement and fill that with the contents of the file, and then process it like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsyncCSV(string filePath)
        {
            int i = 0;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(';');
                    var entity = new HeaderText();
                    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                    {
                        property.SetValue(entity, values[i]);
                        i += 1;
                    }


                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

But I can't find a way to create the blank entity - is this even possible or should I just write a dedicated end point every time I want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If by creating a blank entity you mean create a new instance of the entity, you can use a [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) `where TEntity : new()` which only requires you to have a parameterless constructor for every entity type and then you can write `new TEntity()` to have a blank entity instance.

Additionally since you basically want read a CSV into C# objects, you can use open-source libraries e.g. [CSV helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which has built-in support to [read CSV into C# class records](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records/).

Comment: I can make a new controller just for the function and use the generic constraint - is there any what to do it at the level of the Task, though?

Thanks for such a fast and complete answer!

Comment: No problem :) What do you mean "at the level of the Task"?

Comment: Within the CreateAsync statement, statement

Comment: My original answer would apply to CreateAsync method as well - it needs to have the generic constraint, and it can use CSV helper library or invoke your own code that reads CSV files.